# alignment: Alignment.center, isnt aligning the image in center

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to align the image in center of the screen but it not working , can someone help me understand whats wrong with the code? and why the `alignment: Alignment.center,` isnt working ?

Please have a look at the image i attached below , the logo is painted towards the left of the screen and not in the center

[image]

```
            Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:Container(
              child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
              height: 200.0,
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `alignment` from your `Container()` and manage it with your parent widget `Row()` by using `MainAxisAlignment.center`

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Marcel Dz is suggesting correct add `mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,` for row to show image in center

```
 Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    height: 200.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

[image]